# What is this quotient space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups

What is the quotient space $S^{2}\times S^{2}\times S^{2}/\sim$ topologically,
geometrically, and algebraically, where $S^{2}\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and the equivalence relation
is defined as $$\left(p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\right)\sim\left(p'_{1},p'_{2},p'_{3}\right)$$
iff there exists $T\in O(3)$ such that $$T\left(p_{1},p_{2},p_{3}\right)=\left(p'_{1},p'_{2},p'_{3}\right)?$$
Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, by $T(p_1, p_2, p_3) = (p'_1, p'_2, p'_3)$, do you mean that $T(p_i) = p'_i$ for $i = 1, 2 ,3$?

Comment: @user754697  Yes, that's correct. Best regards.

Comment: I *think* it's homeomorphic to the closed unit ball in $\Bbb{R}^3$. I don't have the algebraic topology background to justify it rigorously and elegantly, but I enjoyed trying to work it out!

Comment: @user754697 Thank you for your comment, but do you know what the map for your homeomorphism in your thought is like? Thanks.

Comment: I see it more as a "pillow" shape, a solid cylinder with each of the faces identified into a line segment. We can assume each $(p_1, p_2, p_n)$ has $p_1 = (0, 0, 1)$, the north pole. This means $p_2$ is free to roam on a fixed latitude, which when we quotient out, becomes a line segment. Then $p_3$ can only be reflected in the plane generated by $p_1$ and $p_2$, so we get a solid disk $D^2$, multiplied by a line segment (from the latitude). However, when $p_2 = (0, 0, \pm 1)$, we get a special case, which leads to the faces being squashed into line segments.

Comment: I gave some thoughts to actually generating an explicit homeomorphism, but it will take me some time just to get the formula. Even after that, I don't think I'd want to prove the continuity.

Comment: @user754697 Then do you know about the quotient space $S^1\times S^1/O(2)$? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105108/discussion-between-anticoviru1-and-user754697).